# How I can limit number child of div jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can limit display number (ex: 6) child of div jquery or javascript or other method?

```html
<div class="parent">
<!--START-->
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<!--END-->
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `:gt()`: `$('.parent > .child:gt(5)').remove();` or `.slice()`: `$('.parent > .child').slice(6).remove();`.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this if they're truly siblings as you show. You can do it with CSS. `.parent > .child:nth-child(6) ~ * { display: none; }` https://jsfiddle.net/sLz6tq8u/

Comment: Good option, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/29x4jmy5/)

It can be done as simply using [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) at the point where you want to cut off the elements, and then calling the jquery [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function:

```
$('.parent .child').slice(0, 6).remove();
```

Comment: @JonsonT Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `.slice` method.

```js
var divs = $(".parent .child").slice(0, 6);

console.log(divs.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<!--START-->
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<!--END-->
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```